# put two values in ng model at Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need to show current location storage or current employee wheres the inventory is at the moment

```
<select class=" form-control"  ng-model="location.name">
        <option value="">Choose Location</option>
    <optgroup label="Locations">
        <option value="{{location.resource_uri}}" ng-repeat="location in locations">{{location.name}}</option>  
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Holder">
        <option value="{{user.resource_uri}}" ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name}}</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Can I put in ng-model two values, so if location is not null, i get current Location, if the location is null , i get employee name selected.

Comment: i've created a jsfiddle..[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TFmjQ/6/) over in this jsfiddle tell me what you need in that

Comment: So, if I choose Holder : it will change Holder name and put Location to null, and other way

Comment: i'm not getting you...........

Comment: Basically i can choose only one value, location or storage for inventory. Inventory can be in location or to user. So i a choose location, then it changes location and user isnt selected and other way.

Comment: i think so you mean to say that when you select a Holder you need that holder name, and when you select a Location you need to get that location name.....am i right

Comment: take out a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TFmjQ/9/)**

**html**

```
    <div class="form-control"  ng-app="main" ng-controller="Controller">
    <select ng-model="category">
        <optgroup ng-repeat="category in categories" label="{{ category.name }}">
            <option ng-repeat="subCat in category.items"> 
                <span ng-switch="category.name">
                    <span ng-switch-when="Location">
                        {{ subCat.name }}
                    </span>
                    <span ng-switch-when="Holder">
                        {{subCat.first_name+" "+subCat.last_name}}
                    </span>
                </span>
            </option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>

    {{category}}
</div>
```

**script**

```
var main = angular.module('main', []);
// Main Controller
main.controller('Controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.categories = [{
        id: 5,
        name: "Locations",
        items: [{
            resource_uri: 'ABC',
            name: "ABC-Name"
        }, {
            resource_uri: 'XYZ',
            name: "XYZ-Name"
        }, {
            resource_uri: 'LMN',
            name: "LMN-Name"
        }, {
            resource_uri: 'PQR',
            name: "PQR-Name"
        }]
    }, {
        id: 17,
        name: "Holder",
        items: [{
            first_name: 'Manu',
            last_name: 'Mathew'
        }, {
            first_name: 'Sunny',
            last_name: 'Mathew'
        }, {
            first_name: 'Jacob',
            last_name: 'Mathew'
        }, {
            first_name: 'Vijay',
            last_name: 'Mathew'
        }]
    }];
});
```

Comment: i will have 2 ng-repeats, because i am getting data from two different api, so i will need two ng-models...